# elseif not being recognized - Variable not being assigned correct value

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have written a small script that checks the HostName in a URL for a sharepoint Site Collection and then gives a variable a value based on that HostName but the elseif in the script is not working:

```
$sites = Get-SPSite https://contoso.domain.cs/sites/sc 
$Logo = $null

if ($sites.HostName -eq "contoso.domain.cs" -or "contoso1.domain.cs" -or "contoso2.domain.cs") 
{
    $Logo = "/path/to/logo.jpg"
}
elseif ($sites.HostName -eq "contosoq.domain.cs" -or "contoso1q.domain.cs" -or "contoso2q.domain.cs") 
{
    $Logo = "/path/to/logo2.jpg"
}
elseif ($sites.HostName -eq "contoso3q.domain.cs") 
{
    $Logo = "/path/to/logo3.jpg"
}
else {}
```

The Variable $Logo is always getting the first value "/path/to/logo.jpg" even when the hostname is not equal to "contoso.domain.cs" or "contoso1.domain.cs" or "contoso2.domain.cs"

please help me if you see the error im making. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the way you check the conditions. The entire expression to be evaluated must be repeated after each `-or`.

For example:

```
if ($sites.HostName -eq "contoso.domain.cs" -or "contoso1.domain.cs" -or "contoso2.domain.cs")
```

Could be changed to check each condition explicitly:

```
if ($sites.HostName -eq "contoso.domain.cs" -or $sites.HostName -eq "contoso1.domain.cs" -or $sites.HostName -eq "contoso2.domain.cs")
```

Or you could do it by using the `-in` comparison:

```
if ($sites.HostName -in ("contoso.domain.cs", "contoso1.domain.cs", "contoso2.domain.cs"))
```

As mentioned in the comments by iRon the following technique also works:

```
if ("contoso.domain.cs", "contoso1.domain.cs", "contoso2.domain.cs" -eq $sites.HostName)
```

Comment: Or just: `if ("contoso.domain.cs", "contoso1.domain.cs", "contoso2.domain.cs" -eq $sites.HostName)`. [When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression. If there are no matches in the collection, comparison operators return an empty array.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features)

Comment: @emanresu thank you man, that really helped, i used the last option with -in and it works as intended. and i learned something new :)

Comment: Good point, @iRon, though int his case you're better off using `-contains` than `-eq`